# Proxying COTURN behind NGINX with SSL and other servers

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, turn, coturn

I am trying to use webrtc inside of a difficult network that blocks all ports but 80 and 443 outbound and everything inbound. So I need a coturn server running to listen to 80 and 443 with SSL certs. I would like to run that alongside a REST API server, some websocket servers, and NGINX hosting static files. I am starting from [this working nginx config](https://github.com/Rehab-Robotics-Lab/LilFloSystem/blob/9ee4fc80e6300b77433177e75ef8817694e0f6f0/flo_web/nginx-prod.conf#L1). There is an example in [another so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566225/nginx-load-balancing-a-turn-server) on how to forward on the root. But I wasn't able to get the same thing to work with a path. For example, I would like the turn server to work on `<url>/coturn`. I would prefer the ssl be handled by nginx but it is fine if that job gets passed to coturn.

Can anyone show me a nginx config that handles coturn with multiple other endpoints like this?

Edit:
Here is a very minimal config, just trying to get the proxying to work similarly to [this](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/issues/43#issuecomment-395486247):

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream{
    upstream turn_secure{
        server coturn:5349;
    }
    upstream turn{
        server coturn:3478;
    }

    server{
        listen 3478;
        proxy_pass turn;
    }
    server{
        listen 3478 udp;
        proxy_pass turn;
    }
    server{
        listen 5349;
        proxy_pass turn_secure;
    }
    server{
        listen 5349 udp;
        proxy_pass turn_secure;
    }
}
```

The domain references are given by the [docker-compose](https://github.com/Rehab-Robotics-Lab/LilFloSystem/blob/7813c62710376ef8e535f5307afa5f6834794a2b/docker-compose.prod.yml#L35) that I have running.

But running this through trickleice, I get a non-reachable error. If I instead run coturn [exposed to the internet](https://github.com/Rehab-Robotics-Lab/LilFloSystem/blob/928f0c64542c2d9f234ef75154bf03108ac7e325/docker-compose.prod.yml#L43) then it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Did you get it working? I have a quite similar setup

Comment: @Langohr I did not. Based on continued reading I ended up deciding that it just made more sense to have a dedicated VM for the coturn server.

Comment: This script, makes jitsi work with only 443: https://github.com/jitsi-contrib/installers/tree/main/jitsi-base. I couldnt manage to make it work with our proxy but it may work with yours